# How to build a Firefox .deb without webm support?

Tags: configuration, deb, restricted-formats

I want to alter the firefox package to remove WebM and other features.

I prefer not just to compile sources - I need to understand what in a deb package I need to alter.

I don't want to have a pile of sources which are manually configured, compiled and installed via non package manager route; and was looking for a way to set package config flags on Ubuntu

How do I alter the Firefox's deb package to do the above?

Comment: What is the problem with that route?

Comment: ... so you want to compile a binary without compiling? that's a little difficult unless you find something like launchpad to do the compiling.  Perhaps you should explain in your question what the issue is with apt-get build-dep etc.

Comment: @fossfreedom, there's nothing to explain: I don't want to have a pile of sources which are manually configured, compiled and installed via non package manager route; and was looking for a way to set package config flags on Ubuntu.

Comment: @jippie there was a problem of me not knowing the configuration part of of it, which includes the `editor` mentioned below.

Comment: @kagali-san - in that case - a slight change in the description makes this a good question. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to disable WebM:

1. Open the URL `about:config`
2. Accept the warning
3. Search for `media.webm.enabled` and double-click on it to toggle the value. Set it to `false`.
4. Changes are immediately applied.

Otherwise there is no easy way to disable WebM without recompiling. Recompiling is as easy as:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep firefox
apt-get source firefox
cd firefox-*
editor debian/rules
dpkg-buildpackage -b -us -uc
```

At the `editor` step, adjust the `configure` options.